# Is overriding destructor for automatic object well defined?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, destructor

I had a situation where I wanted to import a call after another call from the calling function. I decided to override a virtual destructor for the purpose:

```
#include <iostream>

struct type {
    virtual ~type() {
        std::cout << "ordinary" << std::endl;
    }
    void method() {
        struct method_called : type {
            virtual ~method_called() override {
                std::cout << "method called" << std::endl;
            }
        };

        this->~type();

        new (this) method_called{};
    }
};

int main() {
    
    std::cout << "ordinary expected" << std::endl;

    {
        type obj;
    }

    std::cout << "method expected" << std::endl;

    {
        type obj;

        obj.method();
    }

    std::cout << "method expected" << std::endl;

    type* pobj = new type{};

    pobj->method();

    delete pobj;
}
```

It seems the overridden destructor is called only using dynamic allocation. Is this intended?

[GCC godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/3jKrqqzeP)

Comment: After calling `this->~type()` the use of `this` has undefined behaviour.    Your code does not somehow morph an instance of a `type` into an instance of the (locally defined) `method_type` which (seems to be) what you are trying to do.

Comment: `obj.method();` does not change the `obj` type. this is still `type`. The compiler calls the destructor `type::~type` after } directly, not using vtbl, since it knows the type of `obj`.

Comment: @Peter I'm still not convinced - could you please write an answer? Possibly quoting the standard. Or maybe link another similar question if there is one.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Although a few too many language lawyers imply otherwise, the standard doesn't spell out every instance of undefined behaviour. There are numerous cases where behaviour is undefined by omission - i.e. where the standard doesn't specify any constraints on what happens.  That's because the standards committee members are mere mortals who don't anticipate such a usage (if nobody anticipates code that attempts to do X, it is impossible to specify constraints on what happens due to such attempts, and equally impossible to specify there are no constraints i.e. make it undefined).

Answer (score 0):

```
this->~type();
```

Any dereference of any pointer pointing to the object or variable referring to the object that exists prior to this line is undefined behavior once you do this.

This includes the automatic storage destructor.

To avoid undefined behaviour in `main` after doing this, you'd have to call `exit` or similarly never return from the scope where the variable exists.

By the time the destructor is finished, the objects lifetime is over.  Almost any use of the object after that triggers UB.  You can reuse the storage:

```
    new (this) method_called{};
```

This creates an distinct object in the storage that `this` refers to.  If this storage has sufficient alignment and size, doing so is fine.  It is extremely tricky to get right, because one of the few ways to safely get a pointer to this newly created object is by recording the return value to placement new like this:

```
auto* pmc = new (this) method_called{};
```

you don't do that.

```
{
    type obj;

    obj.method();
}
```

this is undefined behavior.  The standard does not restrict what the program produced by your compiler does if this code is or would be executed at any point in your programs execution.

```
type* pobj = new type{};

pobj->method();

delete pobj;
```

so is this.