# Is it well defined to recreate an object using its base class?

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, language-lawyer, destructor

This question stems from [Is overriding destructor for automatic object well defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038978/).

Edited, as originally there was undefined behavior, and the discussion was pointless.

I saw the alignment concern (and also read $6.7.3 p9 which insist "and another object of the original type does not occupy that same storage location when the implicit destructor call takes place, the behavior of the program is undefined.") and created the following counter example - which simply constructs a base object instead (and uses rvalue references):

It still only produces expected results from using dynamic memory - my question is still - is this well defined?

```
#include <iostream>

struct type {
    virtual ~type() {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void method() {

        std::cout << "\n" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n" << std::endl;

        this->~type();

        new (this) type{};
    }
};

struct method_called : type {
    virtual ~method_called() override {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    {
        type&& obj = method_called{};

        std::cout << "\ndestr~" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        type&& obj = method_called{};

        obj.method();

        std::cout << "\ndestr~" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    method_called* pobj = new method_called{};

    pobj->method();

    std::cout << "\ndestr~" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n" << std::endl;

    delete pobj;
}
```

[Godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/a87Knzcfn)

Comment: It's not possible to code a counter example to "_... the program is undefined..."_ because appearing to work is one of the possible outcomes of Undefined Behaviour.  You have instead to reason your way out of the issue.

Comment: "_is this well defined?_" - No - and [it does not behave well](https://godbolt.org/z/rW669P57d).

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are correct - that part is UB. But my main question is about the rvalue reference bindings above.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Since the program has undefined behavior in its current state, it's pointless discussing parts of the program as if the undefined behavior somehow could be taken out of the equation. If you fix the UB you already know about and still have questions about something in the remaining code, it'd be something worth exploring.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Done - sorry.

Comment: The rvalue references here are completely irrelevant -- they don't in any way affect the auto objects created; they just extend the lifetime to the end of the block.  So there's no differentce between the references and creating local objects.

Comment: @ChrisDodd But what about the fact that they have the base type?

Comment: `obj` is a reference to a `method_called` (references are not objects) - so the object type is `method_called`.  fyi - it's best to pick names like `foo` and `bar` or base and derived when discussing the `type` of an object.  We end up saying things like the real type of the `type` object is ..... and confusion reigns.

Comment: not relevant -- the reference is just an alias name for the auto-created (and otherwise unnamed) object.  Construction and destruction is based on that object, not on any references to it that might exist -- the only effect of the reference is to extend the lifetime of the object to the end of the block rather than the end of the statement.

Comment: [The new code](https://godbolt.org/z/MjzE3WTK5) seems to exhibit a similar behavior as the old did. Even if you manage to reverse-engineer how a particular version of a particular compiler with a particular set of options lays out `virtual`s etc., the question "_is this well defined_" will be answered "no, not according to the standard".

Comment: OK thanks - I just wasn't able to find the particular section describing the act of extending the life-time of an object when binding a temporary to an rvalue reference.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I'm not a good language-lawyer so I can't cite a particular section. I do hope a proper language-lawyer comes along to give a good answer though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah no I understand know - if it's just extending the life-time of the object and the type of the reference has no influence on this.

Comment: Your naming scheme comes straight from hell and you are not instrumenting constructors. If you did, you would notice that more destructors are called than constructors. This doesn't happen in well-behaved programs.